# How do I not print skipped tags

Tags: python, selenium, tags, cucumber

I am testing a web application using Selenium and Cucumber/Behave in Python.  As the number of tests have grown, I have separated the tests into sections by using tags.  However, when I run the tests - the skipped tests still print.  They do have a #None at the end of each step, but searching through pages of of skipped tests is getting harder and harder to work with.  I am looking for a way to only print those tests that are run.

When it is run:

```
 Feature: Testing alerts             # features/alerts.feature:1
    Scenario: Test Alert on Change      # features/alerts.feature:3
    Given I start on the main page      # steps/step_definitions.py:32 6.297s
    When I click on "Next"              # steps/step_definitions.py:478 5.369s
    Then I am on the "Information page" # steps/step_definitions.py:638 0.869s
```

When it is not run:

```
    Feature: Testing alerts             # None
    Scenario: Test Alert on Change      # None
    Given I start on the main page      # None
    When I click on "Next"              # None
    Then I am on the "Information page" # None
```

Comment: Thanks - that does look better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A co-worker, who is much smarter than I am, found the answer.
Behave has a command line option to not print the skipped tests:
-k 
[Behave Command Line Options](https://pythonhosted.org/behave/behave.html)